# How to get result from Django-quiz app?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

How to get results from [Django-Quiz](https://github.com/tomwalker/django_quiz) app?

I want users to be able to take a quiz. After taking this quiz, the result will be associated with user. I can't find any tutorial or example.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ...
    test_result = "result of the test"
```

I have installed it, set urls and user now can take tests. But the problem is that I can't figure out how to get result of this quiz.

Comment: Please explain me the duplicity.

Comment: oops very sorry, I had two questions open at the same time and voted for the wrong one. Now retracted.

Comment: Ok, thanks for removing :)